# How to access Session in OpenIdConnect TokenValidated even handler

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application in which I have configured OpenIdConnect provider for authentication. The Startup class looks like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1200);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddTransient<IClientDataHandler, ClientDataHandler>();

        services.AddAuthentication(options => .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                ...


                options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async x =>
                {
                    var serviceScopeFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
                    ...

                    await x.HttpContext.Session.LoadAsync(new CancellationToken()); --does NOT work
                    x.HttpContext.Session.Set("clients", Utils.ObjectToByteArray(someData)); --does NOT work

                };}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Though this lets me use HttpContext.Session (by injecting IHttpContextAccessor) in any controller or service, I can't use the Session in TokenValidated event handler. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move `app.UseSession();` *above* `app.UseAuthentication();`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be building the service provider in your event handler.  This is not executed during startup.  It's executed on each request by your authentication handler long after the service provider has been built.

```
options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
{
    // don't do this...service provider is already built
    var serviceScopeFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
};
```

Instead, you can access the *built* service provider from the `HttpContext.RequestServices`.

```
options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
{
    var serviceScopeFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
};
```